# How to compare data from firebase with a string only with parent node in firebase

Tags: python, firebase

I try to compare data from a firebase with a string that I declared in the code. If the string that I declared is found in the firebase the output will print out "Found". The problem is the data is print out but it is not compared the output show "not found", even though the data is present in the database.
I attached my coding, example of the output and snippet of my firebase
[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8vz1.png)
[Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyNi4.png)

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate(r"path/to/jsonfile")

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'databaseURL': 'firebasedatabaseurl'
})
ref = db.reference("carPlate")
firebase_data = ref.get()
carNumber = "ASD 5566"
for child_key in firebase_data:
    child_data = firebase_data[child_key]
    print(child_data)
    
    if carNumber == child_data:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

I expect that if there is a matching data found, the data will print out "found"

Comment: Iterate through `child data`. You aren't iterating deep enough.